# why I am getting Black & White when I render

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, movie-clip-editor

I use Movie Clip and Box Mask nodes to achieve a split screen effect.
When I render (but also in preview) the clips show in Black and White.
I am not sure why.
Can somebody help please?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Color Mix node set to Add, instead of a Math Node. Math nodes output B&W as can be seen by the color of the output "dot":

[image: Color]

Comment: Math nodes deal with a single value, while color mix node will deal with a tuple wtih 3 values (RGB)

Comment: Make sense and it works, thank you very much for the support. Also I did not know that the dot indicate B&W or colour.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Yeah Yellow = Color, B&W = Non-color data, Purple = Vector data. For the most part they are designed to fit color to color, however blender does allow _some_ interchangeability sometimes.